Why do we need a JWT token?
In my understanding, when a client wants to communicate with a server, HTTPS can be used which involves SSL certificate. This is very secured channel where information is exchanged between client and server by means of a session key.
The session key is symmetric which has been generated by means of asymmetric keys (public/private keys).
So I am wondering why there is a need to have JWT in place?

Keep in mind that SSL encrypts the data between browser and server, but it does not contain any way to authenticate a user

Maybe you should ask them instead?

it will help you https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/json-web-tokens

Same reason you need a password (which is exchanged for a session cookie)

Since this answer already explains JWT I'm gonna focus on when it can be a better solution than standard sessions.
The main advantage of JWT tokens is that the server doesn't need to maintain session data, which can be significant for a large service.
For example, to maintain authentications of many users, in a standard session workflow the server has a list of all sessions with the authenticated user data.
Session ID -> [User ID, Authenticated?, Role, etc...]
In a JWT workflow the server doesn't store anything (apart from the secret key to generate JWT tokens of course) and client has to prove who he is on every requests by attaching it's JWT token which the server can verify each time, thus trading some memory space for some computation time.
Note that the JWT token contains some payload such as [User ID, Authenticated?, Role, etc...] but the server doesn't need to store this since it receives it for every requests.
Another benefit, let's say you have many micro services that the client can communicate with, in a standard session workflow we would have to either:

Have the client authenticate to each micro service to create its session
The micro services would need to replicate session data
Have one master service which needs to be queried by every other services to retrieve session data

But with a JWT token the client can just send its token to every micro-service independently, thus reducing the complexity of the system.

--> JWT (JSON Web Token), is a mechanism for verifying the authenticity of some JSON data used to prevent unwanted access to the protected resources. Generally, we often use JWT as Bearer tokens, where the API will decode and validate before sending a response.

That's not true. The token itself can be unsigned, such that the authenticity cannot be checked

@NicoHaase You are getting it wrong.
The JWT tokens are typically used for authentication and information exchange. It can be digitally signed using various algorithms(HMAC, RSA, ECDSA), providing a way to verify that the sender of the JWT is who it claims to be and to ensure that the message wasn't tampered with during transmission.

Feel free to add all clarification to your answer by editing it. "It can be signed" is exactly what I said: it can also be unsigned. Also, the JWT itself does not verfiy the authenticity of any other data, JWT is the data itself
